# Swift Codable Decode Manually Optional Variable

Tags: swift, swift4, codable

I have the following code:

```
import Foundation

let jsonData = """
[
    {"firstname": "Tom", "lastname": "Smith", "age": "28"},
    {"firstname": "Bob", "lastname": "Smith"}
]
""".data(using: .utf8)!

struct Person: Codable {
    let firstName, lastName: String
    let age: String?

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case firstName = "firstname"
        case lastName = "lastname"
        case age
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        firstName = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .firstName)
        lastName = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .lastName)
        age = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .age)
    }

}

let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode([Person].self, from: jsonData)
print(decoded)
```

Problem is it's crashing on `age = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .age)`. When I take that `init` function out it works fine. The error is `No value associated with key age (\"age\").`.

Any ideas on how to make that optional and not have it crash when it doesn't exist? I also need that `init` function for other reasons, but just made a simple example to explain what is going on.

Comment: Compare [What is difference between optional and decodeIfPresent when using Decodable for JSON Parsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46292325/what-is-difference-between-optional-and-decodeifpresent-when-using-decodable-for).

Comment: @MartinR very helpful! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Age is optional:

```
let age: String?
```

So try to decode in this way:

```
let age: String? = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .age)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my model, what I did is

```
var title: String?

...

title = try container.decode(String?.self, forKey: .age)
```

rather than

```
name = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .age)
```

For example for some reason backend passes a numeric value for that key, like `title: 74`. With the 1st method, you will get error message like this (I wrote a unit test for my model), and you can pinpoint the problem quickly

[image]

However, With the 2nd method `try?`, this useful error message will be silenced and will not bubble up. You will still get a valid decoding result `title = nil`, which actually is not true in most cases, if only `null` from backend is supposed to yield a `nil`.

But of course, if you design is that no matter what is retrieved from backend, as long as the type does not match, it will be a `nil`. Then I think there shouldn't be any problem with the 1st method.

Comment: you can also try to use try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .age), this is the safe way to handle it.

Answer (score -5):

This is work for me.

```
var age: String? = nil
age = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .age)
```

Hope for help.

Comment: This is wrong, `try?` just ignores any errors without addressing the real issue, `decodeIfPresent` should be used instead.

Comment: `throws: DecodingError.typeMismatch if the encountered encoded value`

Comment: @user25917 - that's something else. that line of code will _never_ throw an error since the try? just resolves to nil instead of throwing in this case. look up how swift do try catch error handling works if you still are confused.