# Optional value in Codable is nil

Tags: json, swift, codable

My Swift 5 (Xcode 11.5) app saves people in a text file (json format).

The `struct`s I use to decode the json text:

```
struct People:Codable {
    var groupName:String
    var groupLocation:String 
    var members:[Person]

    init(_ gn:String,_ gl:String,_ m:[Person] {
        groupName = gn
        groupLocation = gl
        members = m
}

struct Person:Codable {
    var name:String
    var age:Int
    var profession:String?

    init(_ n:String,_ a:Int,_ p:String?) {
        name = n
        age = a
        profession = (p==nil) ? "none" : p!
    }
}
```

Decoding the contents of the text file:

```
let jsonData = Data(text.utf8)
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let people = try decoder.decode(People.self, from: jsonData)
let members = people.members

for (i,member) in members.enumerated() {
    //print(member.profession==nil)
    //Do stuff
}
```

`profession` was added later on and there also might be more values added in the future but I want my app to be backwards compatible to older files. If `profession` doesn't exist, it should use `"none"` instead (see code above) but when I check `member.profession` after decoding, it's still `nil`. `name`, `age`,... all contain the right values, so that part works.

How do I give `profession` a value in the struct if it doesn't exist in the json file? What's the simplest/cleanest way to do this, so I can also add to it later on, if necessary (e.g. birthday, gender,...)?

Comment: Override `init(decoder:)`, and check the `decodeifPresent()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift Codable Decode Manually Optional Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46728324/swift-codable-decode-manually-optional-variable)

Comment: Why would use the string `"none"` to indicate a non-existent profession? `nil` is made for that exact purpose!

Comment: @Sweeper That's just an example. I need the String to have a value !=nil that's then displayed in my app without further checking.

Comment: @Larme I saw that question before I posted this one but honestly, I have no idea how that would work because not only do I not use enums but the two code paragraphs I posted above are also in 2 separate swift files. Plus, I don't just want to check if the `profession` exists in the json file, I also want to give it a custom value if it doesn't.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46728424/1801544 use `decodeIfPresent()`. If you don't know where to put it in `init(from decoder: Decoder) throws`. Look for "Swift Codable Custom init".

Comment: @Larme Like I said, I don't use enums/CodingKeys. How do I give the decoded `profession` (which is nil if it doesn't exist) a value?

Comment: They are automatically generated! How do you think it match the names? See https://pastebin.com/VXR1sE1Z

Comment: @Larme The `CodingKey`s are? In the other question they're added by hand and the op also gave them custom values, which I want to do but only if a certain one is `nil`.

Comment: You can't use Coding Keys for that. May I suggest you learn more about Codable and CodingKey by reading [this article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) from Apple

Comment: @Larme Thanks for the pastebin. I just tested it and it works but is there a way to do this without the extra `extension`, so it's a bit "cleaner"? I tried to use the new `init` in the original struct but since I use the same `Person` to save the file again, Xcode gives me an error: `Extra arguments at positions #1, #2, #3 in call` (I guess it only expects a `Decoder` at that point).

Comment: Put the method inside the struct declaration, no need to the extension.

Comment: @Larme I tried to do that but I use the same `Person` to encode it and write everything to a file again and at the point where I create the new `Person` instances for that, Xcode complains: `Extra arguments at positions #1, #2, #3 in call`.

Comment: I don't think the OP even know what he's doing lol :) He want things to be automatically but it have to be pretty as he wanted.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thanks for the link. Unfortunately most of it is about `CodingKeys` and "manually" decoding, which Larme already suggested. Is there really no way to have it decode/encode everything automatically by providing a struct with the right structure but also be able to set a default value/change certain values, if necessary? Because that's not part of Apple's documentation.

Comment: @Tj3n I don't know how to do this, that's why I asked. ;) There has to be some way to change/check the value of `profession` after it's decoded automatically without making a huge "mess" of the code.

Comment: Well that's what everyone in here has been trying to tell you :) there's no shortcut.

Comment: @Tj3n So absolutely no way to change the values of what it decoded automatically? What did I do in my original code then with `profession = (p==nil) ? "none" : p!`? Is that init not being called automatically when it tries to decode the text?

Comment: @Larme Nevermind, the special `init` does work if it's in the struct BUT to also create the objects for the encoding the other init (the code I posted above but without `optional`) is needed too. Is `self` (for `name` and `age`) really necessary though? It works fine without. Something new I learned today: No need to create an `init` for a `struct ` if you want to set all of the properties with it. Apparently Swift creates an invisible one that you can use with the argument labels. Want to post your pastebin code as answer too? I think you posted it a couple of minutes before PGDev did.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to parse your *JSON* in some way other than what `Codable` already does, you need to implement the *custom initializer* **`init(from:)`**, i.e.

```
struct Person:Codable {
    var name:String
    var age:Int
    var profession: String
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.age = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .age)
        if let profession = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .profession) {
            self.profession = profession
        } else {
            self.profession = "none"
        }
    }
}
```

Also, since you're always giving a value to `profession`, no need to make it `optional`.

Comment: Larme linked a pastebin with this code, with the only difference that he added `extension Person` with the `init` inside. I first tried it without and put the new `init` in the original struct but Xcode gives me an error when I want to save the changes in the file again, using the same `Person`: `Extra arguments at positions #1, #2, #3 in call`.

Comment: Nevermind, this does work if it's in the struct BUT to also create the objects for the encoding the other init (the code I posted above but without `optional`) is needed too. Is `self` (for `name` and `age`) really necessary though? It works fine without.

Comment: Well using `self` with the properties is just a coding style that one follow. You can write without it whatever you're comfortable with.

Comment: I see. I know that you do need the `self` for `profession` though, so it'll use the right one.