# How to decode an empty array from Firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46292325/what-is-difference-between-optional-and-decodeifpresent-when-using-decodable-for) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46728324/swift-codable-decode-manually-optional-variable?noredirect=1&lq=1) and spent many hours perusing SO, but I can't seem to figure out how to properly use Decode with an empty array.

**Original Code**

At first, I had no problems with my code.

Here was my original struct:

```
struct JobHabit: Codable {
    var name: String
    var description: String
    var assigned: String
    var order: Int
    var category: Category
    var active: Bool
    var altName: String
    var altNameDate: Double
    var altAssigned: String
    var altCategory: Category
    var altOrder: Int

    enum Category: String, Codable {
    
        case dailyJobMorning
        case dailyJobEvening
        case weeklyJob1
        case weeklyJob2
        case jobBonus
    
        case quickPoints
        case jobJar

        case dailyHabit
        case weeklyHabit
        case habitBonus
    }
}
```

And here was my function:

```
static func observeJobs(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    
    FB.ref
        .child(FB.jobs)
        .observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            guard snapshot.exists() else {
                completion()
                return
            }
            
            for item in snapshot.children {
                
                guard let snap = item as? DataSnapshot else { return }
                guard let value = snap.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
                
                do {
                    let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: value, options: [])
                    let habit = try JSONDecoder().decode(JobHabit.self, from: jsonData)
                    
                    jobsMasterList.append(habit)
                    
                } catch let error {

                    print(error)
                    manuallyDecodeJobHabitAndAddToArray(.dailyJobMorning, value)
                }
            }
            
            completion()
        })
}
```

That all worked great. No problems.

**But then...**

I added in another parameter to the struct. I added in a `points` parameter that could potentially be empty. It's not optional, but it could be empty. (It's the last parameter.)

Like this:

```
struct JobHabit: Codable {
    var name: String
    var description: String
    var assigned: String
    var order: Int
    var category: Category
    var active: Bool
    var altName: String
    var altNameDate: Double
    var altAssigned: String
    var altCategory: Category
    var altOrder: Int
    var points: [Point]    // <=== new parameter that messed everything up
}
```

And that caused the `decode` function to fail with this error:

> keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "points", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "points", intValue: nil) ("points").", underlyingError: nil))

The error makes sense. The decoder can't find a value. Well, if it's empty, then Firebase will return nothing. So that's expected behavior. But why can't the decoder account for that?

I read up on decoding optional values and came up with an initializer for the struct, like so:

```
struct JobHabit: Codable {
    var name: String
    var description: String
    var assigned: String
    var order: Int
    var category: Category
    var active: Bool
    var altName: String
    var altNameDate: Double
    var altAssigned: String
    var altCategory: Category
    var altOrder: Int
    var points: [Point]

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.description = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .description)
        self.assigned = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .assigned)
        self.order = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .order)
        self.category = try container.decode(Category.self, forKey: .category)
        self.active = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .active)
        self.altName = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .altName)
        self.altNameDate = try container.decode(Double.self, forKey: .altNameDate)
        self.altAssigned = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .altAssigned)
        self.altCategory = try container.decode(Category.self, forKey: .altCategory)
        self.altOrder = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .altOrder)
        self.points = try container.decodeIfPresent([Point].self, forKey: .points) ?? []
    }
}
```

That created a new issue. The issue is that I can't create new instances of my struct anywhere else in the app. When I try doing this:

```
static let job120 = JobHabit(name: " Bills & finances",
                             description: "record receipts\nupdate accounts\npay bills\nfiling (max 1 hour)",
                             assigned: "none",
                             order: 19,
                             category: .weeklyJob1,
                             active: false,
                             altName: " Bills & finances",
                             altNameDate: 0,
                             altAssigned: "none",
                             altCategory: .weeklyJob1,
                             altOrder: 19,
                             points: [])
```

I get the following error message:

> Extra argument 'name' in call

Apparently, the initializer is making it so I can't create new instances of the struct? I'm really struggling to figure out how to decode a potentially empty array from Firebase.

What am I doing wrong? Everything worked fine with decoding BEFORE I added in that empty `points` array. Once I added in the `points` parameter, decode couldn't handle it, and so I had to add in the initializers in the struct. Now my other code doesn't work.

Oh, and here is my JSON tree sample:

```
{
  "-MOESVPtiXtXQh19sWBP" : {
    "active" : true,
    "altAssigned" : "Dad",
    "altCategory" : "dailyJobMorning",
    "altName" : " Morning Job Inspections",
    "altNameDate" : 0,
    "altOrder" : 0,
    "assigned" : "Dad",
    "category" : "dailyJobMorning",
    "description" : "set job timer\nvisually inspect each person's job...",
    "name" : " Morning Job Inspections",
    "order" : 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have an API, which can return a struct with either filled or empty value, you **must** declare this variable as an optional. In other case how are you going to handle it in your code later?

As apple documentation says, an optional is:

> A type that represents either a wrapped value or nil, the absence of a value.

Doesn't this make sense?

So to fix existing issues just declare your `points` variable as `[Point]?`. If there is no value for `points` presented in your API response, it will remain `nil`. Later in your code use standard optionals' unwrappers to check whether there is value presented or not.

Comment: I see. I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: Okay, so I changed the points variable to be an optional. I did as you suggested and changed `[Point]` into `[Point]?`. It appears to be working. Wow! What a simple solution. I was hoping it was something that simple. Thanks! I'll keep you posted if there are any more problems.