# How do I decode JSON in Swift when it's an array and the first item is a different type than the rest?

Tags: json, swift, struct, jsondecoder

Say the JSON looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Spot",
        "breed": "dalmation"
    },
    {
        "color": "green",
        "eats": "lettuce"
    },
    {
        "color": "brown",
        "eats": "spinach"
    },
    {
        "color": "yellow",
        "eats": "cucumbers"
    }
]
```

Where the first item in the JSON responses you get back from the API are always a dog, and all the ones after that are always turtles. So item 0 is dog, items 1 through N-1 are turtles.

How do I parse this into something that I can read, like:

```
struct Result: Codable {
    let dog: Dog
    let turtles: [Turtle]
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can implement a custom decoder for your `Result` struct.

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()

    // Assume the first one is a Dog
    self.dog = try container.decode(Dog.self)

    // Assume the rest are Turtle
    var turtles = [Turtle]()

    while !container.isAtEnd {
        let turtle = try container.decode(Turtle.self)
        turtles.append(turtle)
    }

    self.turtles = turtles
}
```

With a minor amount of work you could support the `Dog` dictionary being anywhere within the array of `Turtle` dictionaries.

Since you declared that your structs are Codable and not just Decodable, you should also implement the custom `encode(to:)` from Encodable but that is an exercise left to the reader.

Answer (score 2):

So your `Array` contains two types of element. It is a good example of `Type1OrType2` problem. For this type of cases, you can consider using `enum` with associated type. For your case, you need a `Codable` enum with custom implementation of `init(from:) throws` & `func encode(to:) throws`

```
enum DogOrTurtle: Codable {
    case dog(Dog)
    case turtle(Turtle)

    struct Dog: Codable {
        let name: String
        let breed: String
    }

    struct Turtle: Codable {
        let color: String
        let eats: String
    }
}

extension DogOrTurtle {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        do {
            // First try to decode as a Dog, if this fails then try another
            self = try .dog(container.decode(Dog.self))
        } catch {
            do {
                // Try to decode as a Turtle, if this fails too, you have a type mismatch
                self = try .turtle(container.decode(Turtle.self))
            } catch {
                // throw type mismatch error
                throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(DogOrTurtle.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Encoded payload conflicts with expected type, (Dog or Turtle)") )
            }
        }
    }
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
        case .dog(let dog):
            try container.encode(dog)
        case .turtle(let turtle):
            try container.encode(turtle)
        }
    }
}
```

With this approach, you won't need to worry about the ordering of the `Dog` or `Turtle` in your array. The elements can appear at any order and any numbers.

**Usage:** (I've purposefully moved the dog at the third index though)

```
let jsonData = """
[
    {
        "color": "green",
        "eats": "lettuce"
    },
    {
        "color": "brown",
        "eats": "spinach"
    },
    {
        "name": "Spot",
        "breed": "dalmation"
    },
    {
        "color": "yellow",
        "eats": "cucumbers"
    }
]
""".data(using: .utf8)!

do {
    let array = try JSONDecoder().decode([DogOrTurtle].self, from: jsonData)
    array.forEach { (dogOrTurtle) in
        switch dogOrTurtle {
        case .dog(let dog):
            print(dog)
        case .turtle(let turtle):
            print(turtle)
        }
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: There anymore info on this `Type1OrType2` problem? @nayem

Comment: @SirCJ, yes you can find similar pattern: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47935705/using-codable-with-key-that-is-sometimes-an-int-and-other-times-a-string), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48866751/json-parsing-using-decodable)