# Swift Codable null handling

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable, decodable

I have a struct that parse JSON using `Codable`.

```
struct Student: Codable {
    let name: String?
    let amount: Double?
    let adress: String?
}
```

Now if the amount value is coming as null the JSON parsing is failing.

So should I manually handle the null cases for all the `Int` and `Double` that are present in the `Student` struct?

The `String` values coming as null is automatically handled.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46292325/what-is-difference-between-optional-and-decodeifpresent-when-using-decodable-for ? By overriding `init(from decoder:)`. On accepted answer, there seems to be a "Int" value as "Null".

Comment: A `null` value (no string) is treated as `nil` by default so the decoding is supposed to succeed if the property is optional. By the way: You can omit the CodingKeys.

Comment: @vadian - you mean I don't need to handle it separately ? As others have suggested

Comment: If the name of the properties are the same as the keys you don't need explicit `CodingsKeys`. Name the property as (correctly spelled) `address` and delete the entire enum.

Comment: @vadian - u said -- A null value for Int / Double is treated as nil by default so the decoding is supposed to succeed if the property is optional.  So there is no need for extra conding to handle the cases. OR I have to write decodeIfPresent for all the Int/Double

Comment: It's not necessary to write a custom initializer. Declaring the properties as optional (`?`) is sufficient. That's a part of the magic of `Codable`. However if the `null` value is a string `"null"` you have to write a custom initializer and then please blame the owner of the service for sending this awful JSON.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Can you show the JSON that doesn't decode for you? Adding `"amount": null` to my JSON works fine.

Comment: for every one trying to achieve these kind of requirements, You can use this pod. 
https://github.com/muhammadali2012/Model

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Let me do this Playground for you since an example shows you more than a hundred words:

```
import Cocoa

struct Student: Codable {
    let name: String?
    let amount: Double?
    let adress: String?
}

let okData = """
 {
  "name": "here",
  "amount": 100.0,
  "adress": "woodpecker avenue 1"
 }
 """.data(using: .utf8)!

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let okStudent = try decoder.decode(Student.self, from:okData)
print(okStudent)

let nullData = """
 {
 "name": "there",
 "amount": null,
 "adress": "grassland 2"
 }
 """.data(using: .utf8)!

let nullStudent = try decoder.decode(Student.self, from:nullData)
print(nullStudent)
```

`null` is handled just fine if you define your structs using optionals. I would however advise against it if you can avoid it. Swift provides the best support I know to help me *not* forgetting to handle `nil` cases wherever they may occur, but they are still a pain in the ass.

Comment: when i'm trying to code a null int and send it to my web api, the int disrepair from the json, and i need to send a null int to the server, any way to fix that?

Comment: @BenShabat You should post your code as a question and show the JSON you would like to send. I am not sure if JSONEncoder will send fields with null, but you should provide more context than you can reasonably post in a comment. You can post a link to your question as a comment if you like.

Answer (score 26):

Was browsing through Codable and got this issue.

So to be very clear here it is,
If the JSON/response would contain `null` as the value, its interpreted as `nil`. And hence for that reason one of the model's property which might contain `null` should be marked as optional.

For Example, consider the below JSON response,

```
{
"name": "Steve",
"amount": null,
"address": "India"
}
```

The model should be as below, cos `amount` is returning `null`.

```
struct Student: Codable {
    let name: String
    let amount: Double?
    let address: String
}
```

`Suggestion`: In case, if you would write a `init(from decoder: Decoder) throws`, always use something like below, for optional properties.

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        amount = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .amount)
        //so on...
    }
```

Even if you add `do-catch` block with `try? decoder....` it can be captured if fails. Hope thats clear!! Its simple but very difficult to find the issue even if the model is containing 5 or more properties with some containing `null` values

Comment: you made address optional. amount should be optional.

Comment: @VinayakGH Knowing about `decodeIfPresent` is what helped me out today.

Comment: I am getting the null value like "<null>" how I should validate this kind of response in Decoder?

Comment: @HariNarayananYou need covert JSON to data using utf8 before doing decode. Like let data = json.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8). It will convert <null> to null Now you use this data to decode. I hope it helps.

Comment: How to handle if i got whole dictionary as a null like below ?
[
  {
    "name": "Steve",
    "amount": null,
    "address": "India"
  },
  {
       null
  }
]

Comment: for those trying to avoid the init function you can use https://github.com/muhammadali2012/Model