# Handling null values from JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to call an API which gives me a json response which I am parsing by using JSON Decoder and decodable structs.

For example, JSON data is:

```
{
 "value":[
  {
   "name":abc
  },
  {
   "name":null
  }
 ]
}
```

The structs are something like this:

```
struct output: Decodable {
    let value: [value]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case value = "value"
    }
}

struct value: Decodable {
    let name: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "name"
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to handle this scenario when I get null values because
the decoder gives error serializing JSON.

Comment: Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49894198/6541007).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
let name: String
```

with

```
let name: String?
```

---

```
{
 "value":[
  {
   "name":"abc"
  },
  {
   "name":null
  }
 ]
}
```

---

Also no need for the `CodingKeys` if the keys are the same

```
struct Output: Decodable { // start structs with capital letter 
    let value: [Value] 
}

struct Value: Decodable {
    let name: String?
}
```