# Parse JSON nil value using Coding Protocol

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift4

Let assume I have the class `Opportunity`, with an optional `code` field

```
class Opportunity: Codable {

    let id: String
    let code: String?

    enum OpportunityKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case id = "opportunityId"
        case code = "opportunityCode"
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: OpportunityKeys.self)

        id = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        if let code = try? values.decode(String.self, forKey: .code) {
            self.code = code
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to parse a nil value better than using `if let`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is difference between optional and decodeIfPresent when using Decodable for JSON Parsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46292325/what-is-difference-between-optional-and-decodeifpresent-when-using-decodable-for)

Comment: @Larme, thanks for pointing this, but what I m asking is is there a better way to parse nil value other than if let. The other question is asking the difference between decode and decodeIfPresent. I believe they're different! What do you think?

Comment: If it can be nil, then use `decodeIfPresent()` as said in the linked question and by @vadian.

Comment: For future reference, `decodeIfPresent` is the default method called for optional properties in a synthesized `init(from:)`. This means that if you let the compiler synthesize this (rename `OpportunityKeys` to `CodingKeys` and delete your `init(from:)` implementation), you’d get the same behavior out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way

```
code = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .code)
```

Avoid `try?` as much as possible.

Comment: I'd like to see a reason for this statement.

Comment: @gnasher729 Especially `Codable` relies heavily on error handling. Almost every API `throws`. To write reliable code it's much better to handle the error rather than ignoring it.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, there is.

Since `code` is optional **Just replace**

```
if let code = try? values.decode(String.self, forKey: .code) {
    self.code = code
}
```

**By**

```
code = try? values.decode(String.self, forKey: .code)
```

Comment: using try?, you are going to set code to nil on both cases: 1-decoding failure( due to type mismatch ) and 2-decoding failure( due to missing key).  You may need to use decodeIfPresent as cited to have a change to handle type-mismatch